# Want to place my VS Template to (Visual C#/ Windows) group

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions, project-template

Hi i want to place my new C# VS ProjectTemplate to (Visual C#/ Windows) group(Like DX Template Gallery on my screenshot). How i can do this?

He gets in Visual C# but not on Visual C#/Windows group.

My Code:

```
<TemplateData>
<Name>My Template Gallery</Name>
<Description>Start Template Gallery</Description>
<Icon>myProj.ico</Icon>
<ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
<ProjectSubType>Windows</ProjectSubType>
<TemplateGroupID>Windows</TemplateGroupID>
<RequiredFrameworkVersion>4.0</RequiredFrameworkVersion>
<SortOrder>0</SortOrder>
<NumberOfParentCategoriesToRollUp>0</NumberOfParentCategoriesToRollUp>
<TemplateID>4d72892d-abc3-428d-8fa7-8421a83d6e0a</TemplateID>
<CreateNewFolder>true</CreateNewFolder>
<DefaultName>Application</DefaultName>
<ProvideDefaultName>true</ProvideDefaultName>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ns3Hy.png)

Comment: Place it in `C:\Users\<UserName>\Documents\<Visual Studio version>\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C#\`

Comment: I have VSIX project that contains this template. I need to that-be after the installation VSIX he went into the desired folder.